# Function to summarize columns after filtering

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I was making a table showing summaries of variables across different groups and was wondering if there was a shorter way to accomplish what I was doing as I feel like the way I'm doing it is quite inefficient and more than a bit ugly.

The code below shows me filtering the dataset three times and making the same summary for each and then combining it back together to review:

```
rbind(df %>% filter(not_covered_poor <= 0) %>% #block1
  summarise(parrishes = n(),
            avg_org_count = mean(org_count),
            percent_poor = sum(pop_poor) / sum(population),
            percent_urban = sum(pop_urban) / sum(population)),

df %>% filter(beneficiaries >= 1) %>%  #block2
  summarise(parrishes = n(),
            avg_org_count = mean(org_count),
            percent_poor = sum(pop_poor) / sum(population),
            percent_urban = sum(pop_urban) / sum(population)),

df %>% filter(beneficiaries == 0) %>%  # block3
  summarise(parrishes = n(),
            avg_org_count = mean(org_count),
            percent_poor = sum(pop_poor) / sum(population),
            percent_urban = sum(pop_urban) / sum(population)))
```

I feel that the way I'm doing this is quite repetitive and would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve. As an added complication, block 1 and block 2 are not exclusive.

Please also find below a sample of the data being used:

```
df <-structure(list(beneficiaries = c(0, 0, 0, 68892, 205, 183, 32177, 
0, 0, 0, 13697, 73, 100, 18476.65, 0, 72, 44, 0, 851, 6917), 
org_count = c(0, 0, 0, 7, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 12, 7, 1, 8, 
0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 7), pop_poor = c(786.293697659804, 6398.52367417127, 
1857.11997728972, 54117.5212028031, 37142.7891478974, 3333.92754036401, 
14336.3136502596, 5044.7040929437, 3793.24401690163, 4526.13649370011, 
5480.9303355273, 27978.0377388054, 1625.32898301499, 13919.3029320743, 
2422.26587424895, 8083.83210112954, 8749.35147557249, 8025.87168983684, 
3414.6386596242, 4792.49947152453), pop_urban = c(0, 6534.39188749942, 
4281.97906335782, 111569.427837663, 58245.5511394264, 3074.07437037037, 
70794.6350911534, 9231.25568050296, 0, 4222.8853486222, 79274, 
75787.9180364836, 0, 71843.09703167, 0, 15430.4896458038, 
17694.306, 0, 0, 75012.5261721893), population = c(2127.80485728877, 
6733.70969445529, 4645.74054828884, 111569.427837663, 72752.3746433005, 
6201.48148148148, 70794.6350911534, 14464.5184589517, 6093.612171349, 
4526.13649370011, 79274, 81501.1485498265, 2770.69662921348, 
71843.09703167, 4025.92013062113, 17095.6012029734, 19971, 
17183, 9613.17985555566, 75012.5261721893), not_covered_poor = c(786.293697659804, 
6398.52367417127, 1857.11997728972, -14774.4787971969, 36937.7891478974, 
3150.92754036401, -17840.6863497404, 5044.7040929437, 3793.24401690163, 
4526.13649370011, -8216.0696644727, 27905.0377388054, 1525.32898301499, 
-4557.3470679257, 2422.26587424895, 8011.83210112954, 8705.35147557249, 
8025.87168983684, 2563.6386596242, -2124.50052847547)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For beneficiaries, you could create a recoded var first that contains both conditions, and then you can `group_by` before summarizing. For not_poor you probably need to run this separately as you do since your filters aren‘t mutually exlusive.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @deschen I think you're right. I was just trying not to add too many things to my already cluttered environment. I also just realised that if I let go of the filters not being mutually exclusive, I could just mutate a new variable with `case_when` and group by that.

Comment: @Roman Sorry, was the wording of the question too broad? I'm genuinely looking for a function to help me not repeat the filtering and summarising so many times. It's not really for help on the specific code above -- I've run into similar problems several times and this was just the example I had on hand. I did try to show the problem with iris and mtcars but couldn't replicate the issue.